# Transition of navbar

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, tailwind-css

**My Navbar component**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { navlinks } from '../constants/constants';
import hmclose from '../assets/icons/hamburger_close.png';
import hm from '../assets/icons/hamburger.png';

const Navbar = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className={`flex flex-col md:flex-row w-full mt-[24px] transition-height ${toggle ? 'h-auto' : 'h-[33px]'}`}>
      <nav className='flex items-center justify-center w-full'>
        <ul className='list-none md:flex hidden gap-[48px]'>
          {navlinks.map((navitem, index) => (
            <li key={index} className={`cursor-pointer text-[16px] text-accent`}>
              <a href="">{navitem.text}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <div className='flex px-[16px] gap-[16px]'>
        <button className="hidden md:flex bg-secondary text-primary py-[8px] px-[8px] rounded-[8px] outline-none items-center">
          Contact
        </button>
        <button className="hidden md:flex border-2 border-secondary text-accent bg-transparent py-[8px] px-[8px] rounded-[8px] outline-none items-center">
          Resume
        </button>
      </div>

      <div className='md:hidden flex px-[16px] gap-[16px]'>
        <img
          src={toggle ? hmclose : hm}
          alt="menu"
          className='w-[48px] h-[48px] object-contain'
          onClick={() => setToggle((prev) => !prev)}
        />
      </div>

      {toggle && (
        <div className='md:hidden flex flex-col w-full items-center justify-center'>
          <ul className='list-none text-center'>
            {navlinks.map((navitem, index) => (
              <li
                key={index}
                className={`cursor-pointer text-[16px] text-accent mb-4`}
              >
                <a href={`#${navitem.link}`}>{navitem.text}</a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;`
```

**My App.jsx file**

```
import React from 'react'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-primary w-full overflow-hidden">
    <div>
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

In this code I want to insert a transition on hamburger menu, but i am unable to do so. how can i add transition to the menu? I am using Vite, React and tailwindcss. I tried implementing following code by applying similiar classes but for some reason it did not work.

I am expecting a transition like following codepen

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/marcmatias/pen/pogqLQK)

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to keep the menu in the DOM at all times, so that transitions can happen. Then, to follow the CodePen:

- Add `h-0` for when the menu is closed.
- Add `h-32` for when the menu is opened.
- Add `ease-out duration-500` for the transition effect.
- Remove `justify-center` so that the menu elements do not move when the `height` changes.
- Remove the height toggling on the parent element – transitions do not happen when changing `height` from or to `auto`.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const navlinks = [
  {
    link: '',
    text: 'Foo',
  },
  {
    link: '',
    text: 'Bar',
  },
];

const hmclose = 'https://picsum.photos/48/48';
const hm = 'https://picsum.photos/48/48?';

const Navbar = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className={`flex flex-col md:flex-row w-full mt-[24px]`}>
      <nav className='flex items-center justify-center w-full'>
        <ul className='list-none md:flex hidden gap-[48px]'>
          {navlinks.map((navitem, index) => (
            <li key={index} className={`cursor-pointer text-[16px] text-accent`}>
              <a href="">{navitem.text}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <div className='flex px-[16px] gap-[16px]'>
        <button className="hidden md:flex bg-secondary text-primary py-[8px] px-[8px] rounded-[8px] outline-none items-center">
          Contact
        </button>
        <button className="hidden md:flex border-2 border-secondary text-accent bg-transparent py-[8px] px-[8px] rounded-[8px] outline-none items-center">
          Resume
        </button>
      </div>

      <div className='md:hidden flex px-[16px] gap-[16px]'>
        <img
          src={toggle ? hmclose : hm}
          alt="menu"
          className='w-[48px] h-[48px] object-contain'
          onClick={() => setToggle((prev) => !prev)}
        />
      </div>

      <div className={`md:hidden flex flex-col w-full items-center ease-out duration-500 bg-slate-200 ${toggle ? 'h-32' : 'h-0'}`}>
        <ul className='list-none text-center'>
          {navlinks.map((navitem, index) => (
            <li
              key={index}
              className={`cursor-pointer text-[16px] text-accent mb-4`}
            >
              <a href={`#${navitem.link}`}>{navitem.text}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-primary w-full overflow-hidden">
    <div>
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```